# ocaml-glpk (glpk bindings) and OASIS

Tags: ocaml, glpk, opam, oasis

Preface: I am new to OCaml, OPAM, and OASIS.

tldr question: How do I properly set up a package with `opam` that is not already available in the repository (I can't just do `opam install X`)? More details follow:

I am trying to include [ocaml-glpk](https://github.com/smimram/ocaml-glpk) in an OCaml project. I installed ocaml-glpk just by running `make` and `make install` as stated in the README, and the given example compiles and runs correctly. However, I am using OASIS to generate the build system of my project, and I am not sure how to set it up. I have the same example (renamed to `glpkExample.ml` in a `src` folder) and the following in my `_oasis` file:

```
Executable "glpkExample"
  Path: src 
  MainIs: glpkExample.ml
  CompiledObject: best
  BuildDepends:
    glpk
```

After running `oasis setup -setup-update dynamic`, I run `make` and get the following error:

```
ocaml setup.ml -build 
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ /home/dimitrios/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamlopt -g -linkpkg -package glpk src/glpkExample.cmx -o src/glpkExample.native
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Cannot find file /home/dimitrios/.opam/system/lib/glpk/glpk.cmxa
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 4 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.
E: Failure("Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlbuild' src/glpkExample.native -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

It seems the glpk library is missing a cmxa file needed to compile a native executable. I am not sure how to fix this. To compile `glpkExample.ml` correctly, my Makefile includes `/home/dimitrios/.opam/system/lib/glpk` and also uses the `OCamlMakefile`, which is extremely long and convoluted. Any help on setting this up with OASIS or how to get ocaml-glpk to work nicely with OASIS would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This website is not appropriate for bug reports. You should really report it [here](https://github.com/smimram/ocaml-glpk/issues).

The temporary solution is to use `CompiledObject: byte` to compile in bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `opam` then it is best to install application with it, not manually. Try to clean up your system and remove whatever you installed, and then do:

```
$ eval `opam config env`
$ opam install ocaml-glpk
```

Afterwards, if `glpk` is packaged in `opam` correctly, it should work with your setup, i.e., just with `oasis`'s `BuildDepends` field and nothing more.

Comment: The version of `ocaml-glpk` on `opam` does not work with the version of `glpk` that I have, so I need to manually install it with `opam` somehow (I can't just do `opam install ocaml-glpk`). Is this done using `opam pin`, etc? OPAM's documentation isn't very beginner-friendly.

Comment: You can't install it with opam, because they do not have `opam` file in the upstream repository.

Comment: So is my only option to manually package it as described [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html)?

Comment: yep, I've just checked upstream Makefile, they indeed have only bytecode version. That means, that you can use `CompiledObject: byte` trick, as @Drup suggested.

Comment: Ah, I see. I changed the Makefile as described in my edit of this question so that it compiles native code, and it seems to be working properly. I'm not sure why it isn't set to compile native code. Thanks for the help.